# Looking for a book about the Brontes and tin soldiers

Tags: story-identification

I read a book many many years ago (20+ years at a guess)

What I can remember is:

1. It involved all of the Brontes as children, including their brother
2. There were toy tin soldiers that came to life
3. There was a genie that they may have called a Djinn in the book

It wasn't by the Bronte's just fiction about them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[*The Twelve and the Genii*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Twelve_and_the_Genii) by Pauline Clarke

From Wikipedia:

> Max is an eight-year-old boy whose family has just moved into an old farmhouse in Yorkshire. He discovers some old **toy soldiers** in the attic and is surprised and delighted to find that they come to life. The soldiers, known as the Twelves, or the Young Men, have different personalities; they are brave, intelligent and very independent, not to mention argumentative. They adopt Max as one of their **Genii**, or protective spirits, and he begins to spend most of his time watching and thinking about them. He learns from the local parson that **they once belonged to the Brontës**, who wrote stories about their adventures. When his older sister Jane discovers the secret, she becomes as keen on the soldiers as Max is.

Comment: That's it! Brilliant. Might try to track a copy down and read it to my kids.